# HttpClient.PutAsync returns 400 Bad Request (.Net Core / Blazor)

Tags: .net-core, blazor, webassembly, webapi

I have a Blazor WASM app and a .NetCore 3.1 WebAPI.  I am calling my WebAPI via a Services class as recommended in Blazor.  However, every PUT call for update I make returns with a 400 Bad Request.  It never makes it to the Controller.  I have tested the API controler via APITester Chrome Browser Extension and the endpoint works correctly.  So that leads me to believe its something within the HTTPClientCall.

Here is the API Method on my Controller

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Update(int id, [FromBody] Country country)
        {
            if (id != country.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            try
            {
                await _repository.UpdateAsync(id, country);
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (! await _repository.ExistsAsync(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }
```

Here is the Service call

```
public async Task UpdateAsync(int id, Country country)
        {
            var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(country);

            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await _httpClient.PutAsync("Countries/{id}", content);

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
```

and here is my Program.cs for the Blazor WASM that registers the HTTPClient

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

            var baseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44395/api/");

            void RegisterTypedClient<TClient, TImplementation>(Uri apiBaseUrl)
                where TClient : class where TImplementation : class, TClient
            {
                builder.Services.AddHttpClient<TClient, TImplementation>(client =>
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = apiBaseUrl;
                });
            }

            RegisterTypedClient<ICountryService, CountryService>(baseAddress);          

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();
        }
```

Lastly, Here is the Startup.cs from the WebAPI

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //Register EntityFramework Core Datacontext for Dependency Injection
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            //Register Repositories for Dependency Injection
            services.AddScoped<ICountryRepository, CountryRepository>();

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Open", builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                    builder.AllowAnyHeader();
                    builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                });
            });

            services.AddControllers()
                    .AddMvcOptions(o =>
                    {
                        //Allow XML as a request Accept type
                        o.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter());
                    });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();      

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseCors("Open");

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: try changing `[HttpPut("{id}")]` to `[HttpPut, Route("{id}")]`

Comment: also, this is wrong: `var response = await _httpClient.PutAsync("Countries/{id}", content);` you never fill in the `{id}`. It should be `var response = await _httpClient.PutAsync($"Countries/{id}", content);`

Comment: Thats it. Its always the small things.  Thanks man